# How do I use properly CASE..WHEN using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, case

I came across this post and it guided me to my attempt to update old code to PDO. My question is am I even in the ballpark with this code? Can I improve it or a better alternative to get it done?

```
   $qur = $db->prepare("UPDATE CASE site
   WHEN $acctype != 1 THEN name=:name, url=:url, lang=:lang, state=:state, hs=:hs, cph=:cph WHERE id=:id && usrid=:usrid
   ELSE name=:name, url=:url, lang=:lang, state=:state, hs=:hs WHERE id=:id && usrid=:usrid
                              END");
                $qur->bindParam(':name', $sname);
                $qur->bindParam(':url', $surl);
                $qur->bindParam(':lang', $slang);
                $qur->bindParam(':state', $is);
                $qur->bindParam(':hs', $hs);
                $qur->bindParam(':cph', $cph);
                $qur->bindParam(':id', $sid);
                $qur->bindParam(':usrid', $userid);
                $qur->execute();
```

Thank You in advance for help.

Comment: We don't know... is it in the ballpark? Is it working? Do you get errors?

Answer (score 0):

I can't even tell what you are intending to do with that `CASE` statement. You have made multiple syntax errors and logic errors.

- `UPDATE` should be followed by the table you want to change, not a `CASE` expression.
- If you use `CASE <expr>`, then each `WHEN` should be a value, not a boolean expression.
- You won't be able to set multiple columns in your `UPDATE` within one `CASE` expression.
- There is no `WHERE` clause permitted in the middle of a `CASE` statement.
- I don't know why you interpolate `$acctype` into your expression when other variables are being included as parameters. Is `$acctype` the name of a column or something?

I'm just guessing, but this would probably be a better situation to form the `UPDATE` query dynamically instead of using `CASE`.